# Handling long path patterns in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

My database contains hotels, reviews of hotels, terms (i.e. words) in reviews and topics (e.g. there could be a topic talking "Staff" containing terms describing the hotel staff) as nodes. Indices on all nodes are present. Relationships as follows: Hotel<--Review-->Term-->Topic

I am currently trying to find an efficient way of querying for topics that have paths to two or more specified hotels. In other words, I am interested in the common topics of two hotels. If hotel A has paths to topics 1,2,3 and hotel B has paths to topics 2,3,4 then the result should be 2,3.

I tried the following below but this seems very inefficient which is very likely due to the amount of possible paths between hotels and topics. Basically each word in a review could create a new path that has to be checked.

```
// show all topics that two hotels have in common
MATCH (h2:Hotel)<--(r2:Review)-->(t2:Term)-->(to:Topic)<--(t1:Term)<--(r1:Review)-->(h1:Hotel)
WHERE h1.id IN ["id1","id2"] AND h2.id IN ["id1","id2"] AND NOT h1.id=h2.id
RETURN h1.id,to.topic, count(to) AS topic_mentions
```

I am wondering if there's a faster way of dealing with this, if I were to implement this in java or similar language I'd probably try doing a BFS starting at each hotel and then taking the overlap of what I find. I am fairly certain that adding the transitive edges as direct edges Hotel-->Topic would speed this up, but my limited database design knowledge told me that this might be unnecessarily redundant and not a good practice?

I tried to do the id matching before the pattern matching with another MATCH and WITH clause, but this didnt speed up anything; I think the problem really lies in the pattern matching itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created something similar for searching KB's, and a direct relationship between Hotels and Topics will make this search dead easy, and it'll be faster. For example, your search for all topics with more than one Hotel in common, you'd use:

```
MATCH (h1:Hotel)-[:TOPIC]->(t:Topic)
MATCH (h2:Hotel)-[:TOPIC]->(t:Topic)
WHERE h1 <> h2 
RETURN h1.id, h2.id, t.topic, count(t) AS topic_mentions
```

Note that this will return a count of all topics *these two hotels have in common*, which may or may not be what you want.

> I am fairly certain that adding the transitive edges as direct edges
>   Hotel--Topic would speed this up, but my limited database design
>   knowledge told me that this might be unnecessarily redundant and not a
>   good practice?

All that would be doing is making an implicit relationship explicit, which is one of things that make graph db's so powerful. There is the maintenance aspect to be concerned about - namely if someone updates the words in a review, then you have to make sure that the (hotel)-[:TOPIC]->(topic) relationships are still valid - but you'd have to do that in your original design anyway, so no loss there.